# The supermoduli space of supertori with odd spin structure and metaplectic group actions

Tags: reference-request, moduli-spaces, supersymmetry, supermanifolds

I'm trying to understand the description of the supermoduli space of supertori with odd spin structure as a quotient of the super complex upper half plane $\mathbb{H}^{1|1}$. Such a description appears for instance in [Supertori are algebraic curves](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01218292) by Rabin and Freund. In particular the action of the modular supergroup on $\mathbb{H}^{1|1}$ is described in their equation (4.2), where a bit surprisingly the names for the standard generators of the modular group are exchanged with respect to the usual notation. The modular supergroup considered in the article is just a copy of the usual modular group. Yet, the generator $S$ (in the standard notation) does not satisfy $S^4=\mathrm{Id}$ but rather $S^4=-\mathrm{Id}$ in the odd direction. Rabin and Freund solve this by considering the identification $\delta\leftrightarrow -\delta$ in the odd direction in $\mathbb{H}^{1|1}$, but possibly a more elegant solution, also suggested by the $(\tau,\delta)\mapsto (-1/\tau,\delta \tau^{-3/2})$ in the description of the $S$-action suggests that rather one should have an action of the modular metaplectic group $Mp(2;\mathbb{Z})$ on $\mathbb{H}^{1|1}$ into play here, and that this action should be
$$
(A
,\epsilon) 
\star (\tau,\delta)= \left(\frac{a\tau+b}{c\tau+d},\frac{\delta}{(c\tau+d)\epsilon(\tau)}\right)
$$
where $A=\begin{pmatrix}a & b\\ c &d\end{pmatrix}$ is in $SL(2;\mathbb{Z})$.

Now, to each superpoint $(\tau,\delta)$ in $\mathbb{H}^{1|1}$ I would like to associate a supertorus, and equations (2.3a)-(2.3b) suggest this is the complex superspace $\mathbb{C}^{1|1}$ modulo the supertranslation lattice generated by $(1,0)$ and $(\tau,\delta)$. Let us call this lattice $\Lambda_{(\tau,\delta)}$. Here is where my trouble begins: in order to say that this construction exhibits $\mathbb{H}^{1|1}//Mp(2;\mathbb{Z})$ as the supermoduli space of supertori with odd spin structure, I would like to associate with any $(A,\epsilon)$ in $Mp(2;\mathbb{Z})$ and any $(\tau,\delta)$ in $\mathbb{H}^{1|1}$ a superaffine transformation $T_{(A,\epsilon);(\tau,\delta)}\colon \mathbb{C}^{1|1}\to \mathbb{C}^{1|1}$ mapping $\Lambda_{(\tau,\delta)}$ to $\Lambda_{(A,\epsilon)\star (\tau,\delta)}$ and such that the cocycle condition
$$
T_{(A,\epsilon_A);(B,\epsilon_B)\star(\tau,\delta)}\circ T_{(B,\epsilon_B);(\tau,\delta)}=T_{(AB,B^*(\epsilon_A)\epsilon_B),(\tau,\delta)}.
$$
While the first condition is easy to obtain, I'm currently failing at satisfying the second (it is even possible I am completely misunderstanding the construction).

Is there any reference where a detailed construction of this supermoduli space can be found along the lines described above?